# How would you match this wall texture

Tags: walls, painting

I’m trying to match the existing wall texture rather than redo the whole wall.

It looks like maybe the texture was done with latex paint and not with a plaster skim coat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not texture from paint (*stipple*).

It is a *heavy orange peel* texture and be accomplished with a can of spray texture purchased from any of the big box hardware stores.

Before spraying it on your wall, I suggest trying it out on a large piece of cardboard or something else disposable. Work from the center, outward, in a circular motion.

*Image credit: Home Depot*

[image: Spray texture can]

[image: texture chart]